# print lines from file based on items in list

Tags: python

I'm stuck on some python code and wondering if anyone might be able to point me in the right direction. I have two text files that are structured as follows:

file1

```
48.1.a  48.1
48.1.b  48.1
48.1.c  48.1
49.1.a  49.1
50.1.a  50.1
50.1.b  50.1
50.1.c  50.1
```

file2

```
48.1   info1   info2   info3
49.1   info1   info2   info3
50.1   info1   info2   info3
```

Note that I have duplicate entries in file1 column 2, and these correspond with unique entries in file2 column 1. For each line in file1, I would like to print the line from file2 that corresponds with the value in the second column of file1, such that:

```
48.1   info1   info2   info3
48.1   info1   info2   info3
48.1   info1   info2   info3
49.1   info1   info2   info3
50.1   info1   info2   info3
50.1   info1   info2   info3
```

I've attempted the following code, which includes using a list to retain duplicate values from file1:

```
list=[]
with open("file1.txt") as file1:
    for i in file1:
        list.append(i.strip().split()[1])

with open("file2.txt") as file2:
    for j in list:
        for k in file2:
            item = k.strip().split()[0]
            if item==j:
                print(k.strip(), file=output)
```

This code does not give me the desired output, I think because of my nested for loops (which may also be bad coding practice?) and how I am iterating over the items in list and the lines in file2. Thanks for any help!

Comment: convert file 2 into a dict with the first column as key and the other columns as a list e.g.. use `defaultdict(list)`. You can then iterate over file 1 and print out the second column and the entry in your dict that matches that second column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enter use the first column of file 2 as keys and their rows as values.
Then it should be easy to access the values from the second column in file 1.

Something like the code below should work.

```
entry_dict = {}

with open('f2.txt') as f2:
    lines = f2.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        l = line.split()
        entry_dict[l[0]] = l[1:] 

with open('f1.txt') as f1:
    lines = f1.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        item = line.split()[1]
        print(' '.join([item] + entry_dict[item]))
```

Comment: Thanks @nkaushik, much appreciated! I elevated this response because it makes the most sense to me at my python coding level.

Answer (score 1):

Since the values in file2 are unique, I would use them as keys in a dictionary, which can be used to retrieve the informations you want.

```
dict_info = {}

with open('file2.txt') as f:
    for row in f.readlines():
        value, info = row.split()[0], ' '.join([row.split()[i] for i in range(1, 4)])
        dict_info[value] = info

with open('file1.txt') as f:
    for row in f.readlines():
        value = row.split()[1]
        print(value, dict_info[value])
```

Answer (score 1):

As described in comments. You can make a dictionary of the entries in file 2. Then use them to look up the entries based on the second column in file 1.

```
def mkentry(line):

    first, rest = line.split(None, 1)

    return first, rest.split()


with open("file2.txt") as file2:

    mapping = dict(mkentry(line) for line in file2)


with open('file1.txt') as file1:

    for line in file1:

        col1, col2 = line.split()

        if col2 in mapping:
            print('%s %s' % (col2, ' '.join(mapping[col2])))
        else:
            print('%s no entries' % col2)
```

result:

```
48.1 info1 info2 info3
48.1 info1 info2 info3
48.1 info1 info2 info3
49.1 info1 info2 info3
50.1 info1 info2 info3
50.1 info1 info2 info3
50.1 info1 info2 info3
```

Comment: Thanks @Paul Rooney, this gets me what I want and shows me some new python tricks